# Eloquent Carbon Error Trailling data when request existing data which is not inserted using eloquent

Tags: laravel, date, timestamp, laravel-5.7, php-carbon

I am trying to create REST Api and get this annoying problem. I am using existing table from odoo database which has several records inserted beforehand.
And i realize whenever i want to retrieve the existing row from odoo, the "Carbon Trailing Data" error shows up. But not with the record which i created through laravel eloquent method.

I have already defined the date mutator and cast timestamp mutator to the correct fields of table in the model. But it's still not getting me anywhere. Is there any way other than updating/deleting the date/timestamp value of exsisting records?

Here is some of my codes

Model

```
namespace App;

use App\Scopes\ActiveScope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Employee extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'hr_employee';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        // Private information
        'resource_id',
        'name',
        'user_id',
        'active',
        'address_home_id',
        'country_id',
        'gender',
        'marital',
        'spouse_complete_name',
        'spouse_birthday',
        'children',
        'place_of_birth',
        'country_of_birth',
        'birthday',
        'emergency_contact',
        'emergency_phone',
        'identification_id',
        'passport_id',
        'bank_account_id',
        'permit_no',
        'visa_no',
        'visa_expire',
        'additional_info',
        'km_home_work',
        'google_drive_link',
        'certificate',
        'study_field',
        'study_school',
        // Work information
        'company_id',
        'resource_calendar_id',
        'department_id',
        'job_id',
        'job_title',
        'work_phone',
        'mobile_phone',
        'work_email',
        'work_location',
        'notes',
        'parent_id',
        'coach_id',
        'barcode',
        'pin',
        'color',
        'last_attendance_id',
        'create_uid',
        'create_date',
        'write_uid',
        'write_date',
    ];

    const CREATED_AT = 'create_date';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'write_date';

    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = [
        'birthday',
        'spouse_birthdate',
        'visa_expire',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'create_date' => 'timestamp',
        'write_date' => 'timestamp',
    ];

    public function Job() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Job', 'job_id');
    }

    public function getNameAcronymAttribute() {
        $words = explode(" ", $this->name);
        $acronym = "";

        foreach ($words as $w) {
            $acronym .= $w[0];
        }

        return $acronym;
    }
}
```

Controller Show Action

```
public function show($id)
{
    $httpCode = 200;
    $message = "Here is the employee data";
    $modelData = null;

    try {
        $modelData = Employee::find($id);

        if (!$modelData) {
            $httpCode = 404;
            $message = 'Employee data not found';
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $httpCode = $e->getCode();
        $message = $e->getMessage();
    }

    return response()->json([
        'message' => $message,
        'modelData' => $modelData
    ], $httpCode);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specify a column in `$dates` array, laravel converts the values of those columns to `Carbon` instances. The same happens by default for `created_at` and `updated_at` columns.

So all below columns need to be valid timestamp columns :

```
protected $dates = [
     'birthday',
     'spouse_birthdate',
     'visa_expire',
 ];
```

If your columns are not timestamps, you can use [`casting`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) :

```
protected $casts = [
    'birthday' => 'date:Y-m-d',
    'spouse_birthdate' => 'date:Y-m-d'
];
```

Comment: this one is closest answer to my problem, i just realize that postgresql doesn't have datetime type, it stored as timestamp but actually it's datetime. so i just tried to cast the field into datetime and it's work! thanks for the answer btw

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown any code.
But from my past experience actually, yesterday had the same problem, first off, use carbon parse to create a carbon instance of the date in order to hook up any other carbon helper methods on the date. 
say you have a date like = `$date = 2019-02-14`

Could now do something like:

```
$d = Carbon::parse($date);
//hook any further carbon helper methods on the $d variable and it should work
```

Comment: edited, include the model and the action. i am using the eloquent method to retrieve the data, should i define the accessor to modify the date field values?

Comment: that can work as well, just set the date as Carbon instance